# REST API signature guidance

Tags: api, rest, url, restful-url

Seeking guidance on REST API Signature for an API.
To handle logistics, we want to support shipping label generation for courier packages.

Which of these would be a more RESTFul way to model these APIs.

Generate Label API : `POST /package/{package-id}/label`.
Regenerate Label API : `POST /package/{package-id}/label/regenerate`.

**vs**

Generate Label API : `POST /package/{package-id}/label?operation=generate`.
Regenerate Label API : `POST /package/{package-id}/label?operation=regenerate`.

Regenerate API ends up creating a new Label for the package, based on updated shipping dates, etc passed as part of request payload.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
POST /package/{package-id}/label
PUT/PATCH /package/{package-id}/label
```

https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/

Answer (score 0):

If the `/package/{package-id}/label` is a 'label resource' that you're creating, then the appropriate method is probably `PUT` here.

But 'regenerating' is a bit hard to explain here. Could you just fetch the label over and over again by doing a `GET` request on `/package/{package-id}/label`.

If 'creating a label' or 'regenerating a label' doesn't have side-effects (such as a physical printer printing a label), then a `GET` might work best.

If 'creating a label' or 'regenerating a label' is not really *returning* a label but causing some external effect in a different system, then it feels better for this to be more like the RPC call you mentioned.

```
POST /package/{package-id}/label
```

Then my question is, why is there a difference between 'generating' and 'regenerating'. It sounds like you're just doing the same thing twice. Do you really need 2 endpoints? Can't the system figure out if a label was created before for the `{package-id}`?

If the system doesn't know the label is generated vs regenerated, and only the client can know I would be inclined to use the same endpoint and add some flag to the request body instead of having 2 different URLS.